# Why does this program stops excecuting

Tags: java, multithreading, terminal

I'm new to Threads and processes and terminal really.
So far it's not going that bad but i'm stuck.

In my chiplotleErrorStream it never reaches:

It just prints all the errors that It can't find a plotter (I have no cable connected). But it never goes to:

```
System.out.println("it never reaches or prints this");
```

And I can't understand why.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;

public class ExecTest {

    ChiplotleInputStream chiplotleInputStream;
    ChiplotleErrorStream chiplotleErrorStream;

    PrintWriter pw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ExecTest().setup();

    }


    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void setup() {

        try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            Process process = runTime.exec("chiplotle");

            chiplotleInputStream = new ChiplotleInputStream(process);
            chiplotleErrorStream = new ChiplotleErrorStream(process);

            OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            pw = new PrintWriter(bw);


            new Thread(chiplotleInputStream).start();
            new Thread(chiplotleErrorStream).start();

//            process.destroy();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public class ChiplotleInputStream implements Runnable {

        BufferedReader in;

        public ChiplotleInputStream(Process process) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                String line;

                try {
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }


     // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


     public class ChiplotleErrorStream implements Runnable {

         BufferedReader in;

         public ChiplotleErrorStream(Process process) {
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {

             while (true) {

                 String line;

                 try {
                     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                         System.out.println(line);
                     }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 System.out.println("it never reaches or prints this");
                 // hoping for errors in the terminal so we see something
                 // but if it doesn't come here...
                 pw.println("dfsfsdfsdf");

                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(100);

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }


         }
     }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


}
```

Comment: Post your trace error

Comment: Post the **full** error you're getting.

Comment: Can you verify you created process without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

You're running a program that expects input before it outputs anything.

So the process you have created is just sitting there, waiting for you to write commands to the `PrintWriter` you have created.

As long as the process is alive and waiting, it doesn't output anything to neither its output stream (your process input stream) nor its error stream.

So the `readLine()` method on the readers you created on those streams are just blocked, waiting for some input to come through. The line that you have marked will only be executed once the `chiplotle` application exits, at which point it will close its streams, and the `readLine()` will get `null`.